# Winforms (later WPF) application state persistence

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, configuration

I have a winforms app, I use a mix of standard controls and Syncfusion controls currently. In a few months or so new modules will be developed in WPF.

I'd like to add some state saving functionality. You know. TreeView x's last open node was y. Splitter X was split to point Y and so forth.

I've seen a few approaches. I've seen using the built in application settings and how to bind that to winforms and WPF. This has issues when your application is modular or the GUI is dynamically created.

I've got a few approaches in mind. I'd sort of like an approach which mirrors Entity frameworks POCO approach. I don't really want to be decorating my GUI code with attributes or deriving it from a special base class that knows about gui persistence, or implementing ISerializable, etc.

Saying that, I'm also considering using attributes to decorate the gui components and sort of duplicating a lot of what the serializable code in the framework already does, but specifically geared towards GUI settings. I also considered just using the serializable stuff, but it doesn't reflect my intent accurately.

Does anyone have any advice they can give on this?

Thanks